# How to display 3 div as "sub-header", "sub-footer", "sub-content"

Tags: javascript, css, footer, html

I need to create a substructure inside my site in which I have:

[image: Result]

Actually I'm doing it via Javascript like (pseudocode):
SUB_Content.height = ParentDiv.height - Sub_Header.height - sub_Footer.height

But this (using outerHeight etc) take a lot of time.

I'm trying to do it with CSS like:

```
#REST OF THE SITE ... 100% 100%
#PARENT_DIV { width: 300px; height: 300px; border:1px solid red;}
#HEADER { background: orange; height: 63px; float:left; width: 100%; }
#CONTENT { background:blue; padding-top: 63px; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box;  }
#FOOTER { background:pink; height:50px; box-sizing: border-box; margin-top:-50px;}
```

Even if I set a fixed size for header and footer, the content will get the whole "father size". I cannot user FIXED or ABSOLUTE positioning.

I tried in many ways but without achieve anything.

The most of tries give me a result like this:

[image]

Is there any tutorial / role I can follow to fix the size of the CONTENT to 100% - header.height - footer.height?

usually the content is bigger than Parent div and it is ok if he puts some scrollbar.
I already tried out all the "display:table-row" etc..

This is a "similar" structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <style>
 #PARENT_DIV { width: 300px; height: 300px; border:1px solid red;}
 #HEADER { background: orange; height: 63px; float:left; width: 100%; }
 #CONTENT { background:blue; padding-top: 63px; height: 100%; box-sizing: border-box; overflow:auto; }
 #FOOTER { background:pink; height:50px; box-sizing: border-box; margin-top:-50px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="PARENT_DIV">
 <div id="HEADER">
   HUGE CONTENT
 </div>
<div id="CONTENT">
VERY HUGE TABLE
</div>
<div id="FOOTER">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #PARENT_DIV {
            background-color: #333333;
            border: 1px solid red;
            height: auto;
            padding: 28px;
            position: absolute;
            width: 300px;
            color: #cacaca;
        }

        #HEADER {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 orange;
            float: left;
            min-height: 63px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #CONTENT {
            background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
            max-height: 500px;
            min-height: 100px;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        #FOOTER {
            background: pink;
            height: 50px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            bottom: 0;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #bababa;
        }

        .clear {
            clear: both;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="PARENT_DIV">
        Parent Div
        <br />
        <div id="HEADER">
            Header
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div>
            <div id="CONTENT">
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
                VERY HUGE TABLE<br />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="FOOTER">
            Footer
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** Moreover you can set height and width of PARENT_DIV to 98% to fit your screen.